# Beep sound at the end of multiple macros running

Tags: vba

Can someone help with vba to have beep sounds a few times at the end of multiple macros running.

Comment: Did you search object browser for beep.

Comment: And [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx) is the "exciting" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a nice effect using the next class code. Firstly, insert a class module, name it `clsMusic` and paste the next code in it:

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function Beep Lib "kernel32" _
           (ByVal dwFreq As Long, ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" _
           (ByVal dwFreq As Long, ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long
#End If

Enum Note
  Ab7 = 3322.44
  G7 = 3135.96
  Gb7 = 2959.96
  F7 = 2793.83
  E7 = 2637.02
  Eb7 = 2489.02
  D7 = 2349.32
  Db7 = 2217.46
  c7 = 2093
  B7 = 1975.53
  Bb7 = 1864.66
  A7 = 1760
  Ab6 = 1661.22
  G6 = 1567.98
  Gb6 = 1479.98
  F6 = 1396.91
  E6 = 1318.51
  Eb6 = 1244.51
  D6 = 1174.66
  Db6 = 1108.73
  c6 = 1046.5
  B6 = 987.767
  Bb6 = 932.328
  A6 = 880
  Ab5 = 830.609
  G5 = 783.991
  Gb5 = 739.989
  F5 = 698.456
  E5 = 659.255
  Eb5 = 622.254
  D5 = 587.33
  Db5 = 554.365
  c5 = 523.251
  B5 = 493.883
  Bb5 = 466.164
  A5 = 440
  Ab4 = 415.305
  G4 = 391.995
  Gb4 = 369.994
  F4 = 349.228
  E4 = 329.628
  Eb4 = 311.127
  D4 = 293.665
  Db4 = 277.183
  c4 = 261.626
  B4 = 246.942
  Bb4 = 233.082
  A4 = 220
  Ab3 = 207.652
  G3 = 195.998
  Gb3 = 184.997
  F3 = 174.614
  E3 = 164.814
  Eb3 = 155.563
  D3 = 146.832
  Db3 = 138.591
  c3 = 130.813
  B3 = 123.471
  Bb3 = 116.541
  A3 = 110
  Ab2 = 103.826
  G2 = 97.9989
  Gb2 = 92.4986
  F2 = 87.3071
  E2 = 82.4069
  Eb2 = 77.7817
  d2 = 73.4162
  Db2 = 69.2957
  c2 = 65.4064
  B2 = 61.7354
  Bb2 = 58.2705
  A2 = 55
  Ab1 = 51.9131
  G1 = 48.9994
  Gb1 = 46.2493
  f1 = 43.6535
  E1 = 41.2034
  Eb1 = 38.8909
  d1 = 36.7081
  Db1 = 34.6478
  c1 = 32.7032
  B1 = 30.8677
  Bb1 = 29.1352
  A1 = 27.5
End Enum

Public Sub Play(myNote As Note, mySeconds As Long, Optional times As Integer = 1)
Dim i As Integer
If times >= 1 Then
    For i = 1 To times
        Beep myNote, (mySeconds * 300)
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

It creates musical notes...
Then, at the end of your code use something like this:

```
Sub MusicTest()
  Dim Muz As New clsMusic
      Muz.Play c4, 1
      Muz.Play E4, 1
      Muz.Play G4, 1
      Muz.Play c5, 3
End Sub
```

I must mention that I am not the father of the code. I have it in my collection of nice codes. I took it from internet some years before and I do not know who posted it to send the credit in that direction...

Comment: ok so im getting this part    ( Private Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" _
           (ByVal dwFreq As Long, ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long)  of the code in the clase module in red, that cant be good. Still playing with it.

Comment: just chanced the kernel32 of that part, to kernel64, witch is my system, the error is as follows: the code int his poriject must be updated for use on 64-bit systmen. please review and update declare statements  and then mark them with the ptrSafe attribute.  any idea how to approach?

Comment: No problem. That part is not compilled by your system. It is normal to be red. Use the code like it is!

Comment: Now I go to bed. It is late in my country. If you cannot handle it, tomorrow will be another day, to...:)

Comment: @hugo: Did it work for you, as it is? If not, please tell me what Excel version do you use, is ist 64 or 32 bit and what SO do you use (also 64, 32 bit). I will show you how to make it working for any case. If your Excel version uses VBA less then 7 we must change something in the declarations area.